# Verified IPN with empty data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I will try to get this straight.

I use integrated PayPal Adaptive Payments and implemented IPN, using ASP.NET MVC and C#. I tried the IPN simulator and everything is fine. I got the call and processed the data. The problem is when it comes to payment with the test accounts I made. The payment succeeds and I receive "Verified", but there is not data about the payer or the transaction, or anything. In my PayPal account all transactions are successful. I can post my code, but I don't see how this will help. The thing is that it works perfectly well when sending the IPN from the simulator, but it is not working properly when sandbox sends the IPN after a successful payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to tell exactly what your problem might be.  I've never used their test tool but here's some code that is working with both Sandbox and production versions.  Note that the original POST data actually has the transaction information.  In my case I only care about the data in the memo field.  MVC binding ensures its populated.

One more thing you might want to check... when logged into PayPal you can see the IPN history and see the content of each message sent.  Perhaps that is the problem.

```
    public class IPNController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IPaymentManager _paymentManager;
        private readonly IIdentityManager _identityManager;

        public IPNController(ILogger logger, IPaymentManager paymentManager, IIdentityManager identityManager)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _paymentManager = paymentManager;
            _identityManager = identityManager;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public HttpStatusCodeResult Receive(PayPalCheckoutInfo info)
        {
            //Fire and forget verification task
            Task.Run(() => VerifyTask(Request, info.Memo));

            //Reply back a 200 code
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

        private void VerifyTask(HttpRequestBase ipnRequest, string memo)
        {
            try
            {
                var verificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Application.PayPalIPNUrl);

                //Set values for the verification request
                verificationRequest.Method = "POST";
                verificationRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                var param = Request.BinaryRead(ipnRequest.ContentLength);
                var strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);

                //Add cmd=_notify-validate to the payload
                strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + strRequest;
                verificationRequest.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

                //Attach payload to the verification request
                var streamOut = new StreamWriter(verificationRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
                streamOut.Write(strRequest);
                streamOut.Close();

                //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
                var streamIn = new StreamReader(verificationRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                var verificationResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
                streamIn.Close();

                var transactionIdentifier = memo.Split(':')[1].Trim();

                //_logger.Info($"strRequest: {strRequest}");
                //_logger.Info($"verificationResponse: {verificationResponse}");

                // We receive 2 messages from PayPal.  Only complete this for one...
                if (verificationResponse.Equals("VERIFIED"))
                {
                    if (strRequest.Contains("payment_type=instant"))
                    {
                        _paymentManager.CompleteTransaction(transactionIdentifier);
                        _logger.Info($"IPNController.VerifyTask.  Payment marked as 'Paid'. transactionIdentifier={transactionIdentifier}");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.Warn($"IPNController.VerifyTask.  A non-verified request was received.  transactionIdentifier={transactionIdentifier}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("IPNController.VerifyTask", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public class PayPalCheckoutInfo
    {
        public string Memo { get; set; }

        //mc_gross=6.15
        //protection_eligibility=Ineligible
        //payer_id=ZJ93C8BT7HYE4
        //tax=0.00
        //payment_date=21:09:26 Jan 26, 2016 PST
        //payment_status=Completed
        //charset=windows-1252
        //first_name=Sandbox
        //mc_fee=0.48
        //notify_version=3.8
        //custom=
        //payer_status=verified
        //business=developer+application @trytn.com
        //quantity= 0
        //verify_sign = A8RQ0F8gkUzMctcqZ4r9aZzwD7JUA2ltLngw8Dny8kkzavsf9M8bRfZ3
        // payer_email = developer + merchant@trytn.com
        //memo= Trytn
        //txn_id = 52W35468KJ348570R
        //payment_type= instant
        //payer_business_name = Sandbox Merchant's Test Store
        //last_name= Merchant
        //receiver_email = developer + application@trytn.com
        //payment_fee= 0.48
        //receiver_id = VMLFKLT4VDZQL
        //txn_type = web_accept
        //item_name =
        //mc_currency = USD
        //item_number =
        //residence_country = US
        //test_ipn = 1
        //transaction_subject =
        //payment_gross = 6.15
        //ipn_track_id = 245bfe354148e
    }
```

Original Source: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/pull/31/files

Comment: Thanks. That really helped. For some reason it didn't occur to me to check the IPN history. It showed me that the format is a bit different. I fixed it, however I got into another problem with the IPN and going live. But at least I am a bit further down the road. Thanks again